# Accessing Panda dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a Pandas data-frame(df) and a list(List1) containing lot of items which may or may not be data-frame column names. is it possible to print only those data-frame columns whose names are present in the given list.

Eg1: data-frame columns names are: 'one', 'two', 'three'
     List items are : 'one' , 'four', 'two'.
     Wanted to print only 'one' and 'two' data-frame column

```
List1=['one', 'four', 'two']
for item in List1:
    if item in df.columns:
        print(df.item)

Above code throws AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'item' which is perfectly fine.
```

I am just trying to print only those data-frame columns whose names are present in the given list, if it is possible.
Tried to find the workaround from pandas docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html

Comment: `[col for col in df.columns if col in List1]`, or with sets: `list(set(df.columns) & set(List1))`

Comment: @Erfan I am trying to print the data-frame COLUMN and not the common elements of df.columns and List1..

Comment: Then use `df[list(set(df.columns) & set(List1))]` or if you want to print one by: `for col in df.columns: if col in List1: print(df[col])`.